# How can I integrate an excel sheet with google drive

Tags: php, mysql, gwt, google-sheets, google-api-php-client

```
<?php
// Connection 
include_once('connection.php');

$filename = "orders.xls"; // File Name

// Download file
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\""); 
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

$sql="select * from orders";
$qur=mysql_query($sql);


// Write data to file
$flag = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qur)) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
      $flag = true;
    }
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  }
?>
```

This is the code, from which I'm making a downloadable excel sheet of orders. My client wants this excel sheet to be integrated with google spread sheet in his Google drive and when ever a new order is placed on his website it gets auto-updated in that sheet as well. I do not know how to do it. Since it was the first time I have made a website for someone I had no experience.

I asked from many of my teachers they have never heard it before

Kindly please tell what should i do

Comment: You need to post your excel file to the google drive using the google drive api. Thr drive API is described here. https://developers.google.com/drive/

Comment: Particularly in which section should I go and able to do this. Because I haven't even heard about it before. This is the first time i heard this from my client and its his demand

Comment: Can you please guide me more ? I will be very thank ful to you

Comment: Please read this section in the google drive API. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#simple This is the part explaining how to upload files. Additionally, try to read and understand the PHP samples for google drive, that are found on google with google drive php sample as a query. Specifically look at this https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php

Comment: Thank you so very much :) I'm going through  all this